# Error "Attempting to reference a deleted function" - when passing back value of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Test.h

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A GetTitle();
private:
    unique_ptr<A> title;
};
```

Test.cpp

```
#include <memory>
#include "Test.h"

A A::GetTitle()
{
    return *this->title.get();
} // Error here

int main()
{
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> C2280: 'std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr(const
>   std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to
>   reference a deleted function

what am i doing wrong here? Is it down to the ownership of `this->keyServer`? How do i pass just the value back so that i am not at all allowing users of the function to modify the value inside the class without using setter?

Comment: Updated OP with error comment. I'm not yet calling it.

Comment: Any reasons for the down vote guys? I even created a brand new project to isolate the error... and provided all code.

Comment: Why did you pick `unique_ptr` here?  Is it really a resource that only one copy of should exist at a time?

Comment: Well, I thought that i only want my A class to own that title let's say (I know it's made up code)... and i just wanted people to access it but not be able to maniuplate it... so yes i thought unique_ptr was perfect here.

Comment: Given the *Context* update, you don't need a `unique_ptr` at all. Just have a data member of type `B` in `A`. And I'm tempted to revert all your changes since you introduced `B`. With that change my answer is meaningless.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988: The code you've posted doesn't produce the error that you're claiming. Which really annoys people. I currently get an error that `B` is an incomplete type. If I do `class B {};` then I get an error that `setTitle()` has a different return type in the definition vs declaration.

Comment: Ohhhhh I think this is an issue somewhere else!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` is not copyable because of the presence of the `unique_ptr` data member. The `GetTitle()` member function attempts to make a copy of `A`, because it returns an `A` by value, leading to the (misleading) error.

If you want to be able to make copies of `A` you'll need to provide a copy constructor definition.

---

On the whole, your example is odd. If `A` is a unique resource, should you be making copies of it in that member function? And what if `A::title` actually contains a pointer to a class derived from `A`? Then the copy operation isn't going to work as intended.

Comment: You're also copying the `unique_ptr`.  You could also just make it a `shared_ptr` at that point, which would make more sense if more than one `A` with the given pointer exists at a time.

Comment: Great, let me give this a try!

Comment: @Donnie Where is the `unique_ptr` being copied? The error message is indicating the compiler generated copy constructor definition for `A` would copy the `unique_ptr`, hence it's ill-formed.

Comment: I've changed my OP a little, perhaps this makes more sense?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 It makes less sense. Now we need the definition of `B`.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 You've changed it from an example that compiled to one that doesn't. What is `B`? The code should now compile is `B` is copy constructible.

Comment: class B is a value object. It (in my real app) stores information about a window. height, width etc.

Comment: I'm embarassed... as i changed my post, i slowly realised where errors might be coming from! Thank you so much for providing excellent help!

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Glad I could help. But could you please revert to the original code that shows the problem? That way the question and answer might actually be helpful to someone else too.

Comment: Of course... Let me just get to the problem then i'll update it all.